# How to generate consecutive integers in Azure SQL?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am interested in generating a series of consecutive integers from 1 to 1000 (for example) and storing these numbers in each row of some table. I would like to do this in Microsoft Azure SQL but I am not sure if arrays are even supported.

Comment: Do you mean each integer in each row, or an array in each row?

Comment: Each integer in each row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One relatively simple method is a recursive CTE:

```
with n as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from n
      where n < 1000
     )
select n.n
from n
options (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: what do you mean from d? I do not have any other table available.

Comment: @NarekNersisyan . . . That was a typo.

Comment: I would suggest you do this once and then persist it to the database. You will be amazed at how often an "n" table can be used. I attended a talk on it once an have added one to my databases ever since.

Comment: This works, but please note that the correct syntax is `option` not `options`.

Answer (score 1):

Another mechanism to solve something like this could be to [use a SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) on the table. It's similar to an IDENTITY column (they actually have the same behavior under the covers) without some of the restrictions. Just reset it to a new seed value as you add data to the table.